# Error installing 'basicsr' on macOS with pip: OSError - Directory not empty, seeking resolution steps

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, stable-diffusion

i'm trying to install stable-diffusion-webui on mac os, when i run ./web-ui.sh, this error appears

---

```
OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty: '/private/var/folders/8h/x8kgqp2x2h3gryh9v7v9f8r00000gp/T/pip-install-r5hyfavd/basicsr_ec8eabc4b9e0466487ec10fcf881f174/.eggs/Cython-3.0.5-py3.10-macosx-10.9-universal2.egg/Cython-3.0.5.dist-info' -> '/private/var/folders/8h/x8kgqp2x2h3gryh9v7v9f8r00000gp/T/pip-install-r5hyfavd/basicsr_ec8eabc4b9e0466487ec10fcf881f174/.eggs/Cython-3.0.5-py3.10-macosx-10.9-universal2.egg/EGG-INFO'

[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.

╰─> basicsr

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

hint: See above for output from the failure.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.2 -> 23.3.1

[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

---

I need some help.

I'm just a newbie, it might be a problem with the 'basicsr' package, or the operation failed due to the directory not being empty.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by reinstalling a another python version. (Python 3.10.13)